# Question about $\operatorname{Ext}^1_R(A,B)$ seen as a module whose elements are short exact sequences.

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unit and $A, B$ two $R$-modules. What is the $R$-module structure  of $ \operatorname{Ext}_R ^ 1 (A, B) $ like? If $r \in R$ who is $r \cdot( 0 \rightarrow B \rightarrow M \rightarrow A \rightarrow 0)$, where $ 0 \rightarrow B \rightarrow M \rightarrow A \rightarrow 0$ is seen as element of $ \operatorname{Ext}_R ^ 1 (A, B) $?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know how the short exact sequence description is functorial in $B$, i.e. if you have a module homomorphism $B \to B'$ and a short exact sequence $0 \to B \to M \to A \to 0$ you can get a corresponding short exact sequence $0 \to B' \to M' \to A \to 0$?  If so, then you apply that construction to the module homomorphism $r{\cdot} : B \to B$.

Comment: Ok it is clear, thank you.

Comment: If we apply the construction to $r \cdot : A \rightarrow A$, we obtain an equivalent short exact sequence, is it right?

Comment: Sure, using the contravariant functionality in $A$ should give the same answer.  That would probably make a good question to be posted separately.

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are ideals, does $M$ meet any particular conditions?